# How to summarize Complete hours spent on bugs + child task

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Using PowerBI I am trying to calculate the following statistics from my AzureDevOps data:

- Completed hours on bugs
- Completed hours on user stories

The complex part is that we create tasks both under bugs and under stories. 
So when I want to summarize the time spent on bugs I need to know if the Parent to the task is a bug or a user story.

I assume I could add a new column and add some logic that says: If parent = Bug : set 1, if Parent = User Story set 2. 
Then it will be easy to Sum based on the newly added column.

But I am not sure if this is the best option? 
And I do not know how to add logic to calculate the new column. 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=looCm3cbINw

It seems it is possible to do joins :)))!